# `method_missing': undefined method `paginates_per' for #<Class:…>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My rails application is generating the following error (when running rails generators, or launching WEBrick):

```
/home/lachlan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing': undefined method `paginates_per' for #<Class:0x0000000293d7d8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/lachlan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rich-1.3.1/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:13:in `<class:RichFile>'
from /home/lachlan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rich-1.3.1/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:6:in `<module:Rich>'
from /home/lachlan/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rich-1.3.1/app/models/rich/rich_file.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am using the following gems, that I assume may be involved in the error:

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rich'
gem 'kaminari'
```

I have run `rake db:migrate`.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: The full source can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/lunapixel/bottle

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out what was causing the problem.  I was excluding 'Rich::RichFile' in the rails_admin configuration.  Removing this line solved the problem.